# Is there a Material-UI component to search/select tags like in stackoverflow?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for something like this to implement in ReactJS/Material-UI. Any existing component or library for this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the `Autocomplete` component by overriding the `ListboxProps` of the `Listbox` which is the container of the dropdown and set the CSS grid to display 3 equal width columns using the [`fr` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#the_fr_unit):

```
<Autocomplete
  ListboxProps={{
    style: {
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr",
      maxHeight: "initial",
    }
  }}
```

Now assuming the option has the following type:

```
type TagOption = {
  tag: string;
  views: number;
  description: string;
};
```

In the Stackoverflow dropdown, there are only 6 options at max, so we need to restrict the number of options shown in the `Listbox`:

```
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const _filterOptions = createFilterOptions<TagOption>();
const filterOption = (props, state) => {
  const results = _filterOptions(props, state);

  return results.slice(0, 6);
};
```

```
<Autocomplete filterOptions={filterOption}
```

We also want to create a customized option component for each grid item. Here is a minimal example without any much styles to get you started:

```
function OptionItem({ option, ...other }) {
  return (
    <li
      {...other}
      style={{
        display: "block"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <Chip label={option.tag} />
        {option.views}
      </div>
      <div>{option.description}</div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

```
renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
  <OptionItem {...props} option={option} />
)}
```

And finally set the `isOptionEqualToValue` and `getOptionLabel` to ensure that the option get filtered properly and the input display the correct tag when selected:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.tag === value.tag}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tag}
```

### [Live Demo](https://8ydqv.csb.app/) ([Source](https://codesandbox.io/s/69532940-is-there-a-material-ui-component-to-search-select-tags-like-in-stackoverflow-8ydqv?file=/demo.tsx))

Answer (score 1):

That's not a perfect fit, but you can use **[autocomplete](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/)** (using multiple, customizable and asynchronous)

Comment: Looks like https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#customized-hook is what I need, thanks a lot!